# How to open a tab to a file:/// URL Firefox extension developement?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I don't know much about JavaScript. I am trying to open a tab with a file URL and it keeps reverting to the `about:newtab` page. Is it possible to open a file URL in Firefox extension?

Currently I am using:

```
 var updating = browser.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: result.data.url });
 updating.then(onUpdated, onError);
```

Where `result.data.url` is a file URL. It works with HTTP and HTTPS URL.

I am using Firefox 56.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. You can follow bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266960 to stay up to date.